# Solr Block Join Children Query Parser with query that matches non Parent Docs

Tags: solr

I have been using Solr 6.2.1 with nested documents and was trying to retrieve all child documents of a specific type of parent with the [Block Join Children Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers), however I am getting the following error:

> Parent query yields document which is not matched by parents filter

My documents are similar to:

```
<add>
  <doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="type">MYDOCTYPE</field>
  <field name="isParent">true</field>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">1_1</field>  
      <field name="comments">some comments</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">1_2</field>  
      <field name="comments">some more comments</field>
    </doc>
  </doc>
  <doc>
  <field name="id">2</field>
  <field name="type">MYDOCTYPE</field>
  <field name="isParent">true</field>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">2_1</field>  
      <field name="comments">some comments</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">2_2</field>  
      <field name="comments">some more comments</field>
    </doc>
  </doc>
  <doc>
  <field name="id">3</field>
  <field name="type">MYDOCTYPE</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

And I'm trying to query them with: `q={!child of="isParent:true"}type:MYDOCTYPE`

I guess the problem is that document 3 has the type MYDOCTYPE but is not a parent document, it makes sense it isn't as it doesn't have child documents.

Is there anyway to retrieve all the children documents without adding the field `isParent` to document 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround and that is to make the query:

`{!child of="isParent:true"}type:"EDH/MAG"+isParent:true`

this way the second part of the query only matches doc 1 and 2 and does not throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's old question, but maybe my answer help somebody.

It's right that doc with id=3 is treated as child, therefrom error occures.

Maybe we can assume that parent document is document with **isParent:true** or with not empty **type** field and with **id**, then query may looks like this:

```
q={!child of="isParent:true OR (id:* AND type:*)"}type:MYDOCTYPE
```